# How to see the distribution of variables after clustering with gower distance in R. How can i see the distribution of variables accross the clusters?

Tags: r, hierarchical-clustering

I have calculated dendrograms of my dataset with the divisive and agglomerative method

```
library(cluster)
library(fpc)

gower.dist <- daisy(data.cluster, metric=c("gower"))
divisive.clust <- diana(as.matrix(gower.dist), 
                        diss = TRUE, keep.diss = TRUE)
plot(divisive.clust, main = "Divisive")

aggl.clust.c <- hclust(gower.dist, method = "complete")
plot(aggl.clust.c,
     main = "Agglomerative, complete linkages")
```

I also have the results in a table with the amounts of cases in the clusters, etc.

```
cstats.table <- function(dist, tree, k) {
  clust.assess <- c("cluster.number","n","within.cluster.ss","average.within","average.between",
                    "wb.ratio","dunn2","avg.silwidth")
  clust.size <- c("cluster.size")
  stats.names <- c()
  row.clust <- c()
  output.stats <- matrix(ncol = k, nrow = length(clust.assess))
  cluster.sizes <- matrix(ncol = k, nrow = k)
  for(i in c(1:k)){
    row.clust[i] <- paste("Cluster-", i, " size")
  }
  for(i in c(2:k)){
    stats.names[i] <- paste("Test", i-1)
    
    for(j in seq_along(clust.assess)){
      output.stats[j, i] <- unlist(cluster.stats(d = dist, clustering = cutree(tree, k = i))[clust.assess])[j]
      
    }
    
    for(d in 1:k) {
      cluster.sizes[d, i] <- unlist(cluster.stats(d = dist, clustering = cutree(tree, k = i))[clust.size])[d]
      dim(cluster.sizes[d, i]) <- c(length(cluster.sizes[i]), 1)
      cluster.sizes[d, i]
      
    }
  }
  output.stats.df <- data.frame(output.stats)
  cluster.sizes <- data.frame(cluster.sizes)
  cluster.sizes[is.na(cluster.sizes)] <- 0
  rows.all <- c(clust.assess, row.clust)
  # rownames(output.stats.df) <- clust.assess
  output <- rbind(output.stats.df, cluster.sizes)[ ,-1]
  colnames(output) <- stats.names[2:k]
  rownames(output) <- rows.all
  is.num <- sapply(output, is.numeric)
  output[is.num] <- lapply(output[is.num], round, 2)
  output
}

stats.df.divisive <- cstats.table(gower.dist, divisive.clust, 7)
stats.df.divisive

stats.df.aggl <-cstats.table(gower.dist, aggl.clust.c, 7)    
#complete linkages looks like the most balanced approach
stats.df.aggl
```

Comment: I don't understand the question, are you looking for `divisive.clust$order.lab` or `o <- divisive.clust$order;attr(divisive.clust$diss, "Labels")[o]` ?

Comment: Sorry if my question isn't clear. I am looking for the distribution of the variables in the clusters to see on which variables the clusters are decided. I had 3510 cases clustered on 12 variables, but i'd like to see which variables of the 12 were most important for the clusters.